Why is solve returning an error and reduce aborting for this simple equation
I do not understand why Mathematica can't handle this seemingly simple equation:
f[x_] = x Log[x] + (1 - x) Log[1 - x] + c x (1 - x)
Solve[D[f[x], x] == 0, x, Reals]
Reduce[D[f[x], x] == 0, x, Reals]

The solve command returns the error "Solve: The solution set contains a full-dimensional component; use Reduce for complete solution information." while the Reduce command simply returns "\$Aborted[]". What does the first output mean and why does the second command abort? I just want to find the minima of this function in terms of the parameter $c$ and can't figure out why Mathematica can't handle this seemingly simple equation.

The issue seems is that you have free parameter c in there. Depending on which value c has you could get different solutions or more than one solution. That is why it can't solve it.

f[x_] = x  Log[x] + (1 - x)  Log[1 - x] + c  x  (1 - x)
eq = D[f[x], x] == 0;
Manipulate[
 Plot[eq[[1]] /. c -> c0, {x, 0, 1}],
 {{c0, 0, "c"}, -10, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {c0}
 ]

So if you give it specific value for $c$ it can solve it
ClearAll["Global`*"]
c=-3;
f[x_]=x Log[x]+(1-x) Log[1-x]+c x (1-x)
Solve[D[f[x],x]==0,x,Reals]


Another workaround is to solve for both $x,c$ at same time
ClearAll["Global`*"]
f[x_] = x  Log[x] + (1 - x)  Log[1 - x] + c  x  (1 - x)
Solve[D[f[x], x] == 0, {x, c}, Reals]



To provoke you a bit: If this equation is so simple, why don't you solve it by hand then? :)
Looking at the FullSimplify[D[f[x], x] == 0], you will see that the equation is: $$ c x+\tanh ^{-1}(1-2 x)=c/2.$$
Can you explicitly extract $x$ out of this? I don't think so. You can use @Nasser's suggestion to solve this numerically for given $c$:
sol[c_?NumericQ] := 
 NSolve[D[x Log[x] + (1 - x) Log[1 - x] + c x (1 - x), x] == 0, x, Reals]
ListPlot[Table[{c, x} /. sol[c], {c, -1, 5, 0.01}], PlotStyle -> Red, 
 AxesLabel -> {c, x}]


Or use ContourPlot:
eq = D[x Log[x] + (1 - x) Log[1 - x] + c x (1 - x), x] == 0;
ContourPlot[eq, {c, -1, 5}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 FrameLabel -> {c, x}]



The equation is simple in the fact that it can compactly written in terms of elementary functions. However, it cannot be easily solved analytically which is why you posted two means of obtaining solutions which involve numerical computation.
